# Security issue accessing microsoft interop dll sending email

Tags: asp.net

We have a simple piece of code here that recently stopped working and I have tried many 'things' to try and resolve the error.

The code

`Application outLook = new Application();`  :)

The error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070005.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack
>   trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the
>   COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070005.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add
>   the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and
>   check the boxes for the desired access.

Now whilst the error is quite obvious I cannot resolve it.

The application is a .net 2.0 web application and the server is windows 2008 r2 standard using IIS 7.0

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using Client appliactions on a server is always going to be problematic - there are other ways to access mailboxes.

That said, this might help:

http://technoblogy.net/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-00024500-0000-0000-c000-000000000046-failed-due-to-the-following-error-80040154/